# JPA-EclipseLink, pass List as positional parameter to NamedNativeQuery

Tags: jpa

So AFAIK, `named` parameters are not accepted by `Native Queries` **and** they don't allow `List` as parameter, I was thinking that maybe if I "parse" the List into a  comma-separated string, that I could pass this string to the `IN` parameter, is this possible ?

I know that `JPQL` does allow the previous mentioned qualities but my queries are in `SQL` and it would take me a **lot** to "translate" the `SQL -> JPQL` since I'm not an expert on the topic and the queries are very large.

What other solution *JPA-wize* is there ?

I need to be able to pass `List<Long>` to the `IN` clause of my `@NamedNativeQueries`.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit

Although, when implementing the "parse List -> String" I get

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: Invalid number
```

So unless I'm doing something wrong, I assume this is not possible ?

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Client.findTestWidgetResultList",
        query = ""
                + "SELECT DISTINCT sa.event_user_id, "
                + "           CASE WHEN sa.passed_flag = 'Y' "
                + "        THEN 'P' "
                + "        ELSE 'F' "
                + "        END "
                + "    test_result "
                + "FROM survey_attempts sa "
                + "    JOIN event_user eu ON eu.event_user_id = sa.event_user_id "
                + "    JOIN event_user_x_answer eua ON eua.event_user_id = eu.event_user_id "
                + "    JOIN event e ON sa.event_id = e.event_id "
                + "WHERE sa.session_id = 1 "
                + "AND sa.survey_code = 'test1' "
                + "AND sa.event_user_id IN (?1) ")
```

Then:

```
em.createNamedQuery("Client.findTestWidgetResultList")
  .setParameter(1,parsedList).getResultList();
```

Where the parsed list comes from:

```
private String setINClauseFromList(List<Long> l){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    l.parallelStream().forEach( n -> sb.append(n + ","));

    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(","));    

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: since most/all of the syntax in that SQL is easily doable in JPQL then that is the way I would go

Comment: @NeilStockton  Yes maybe for this query, but unfortunately I have more queries 10 times larger :/